# how to choose the reward function to solve an optimization problem with DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, reward-functions, double-q-learning

I am currently working on solving an optimization problem related to the facilities layout using Deep Q-Networks (DQN). The primary challenge I am facing revolves around designing an effective reward function.

In this problem, each action results in a new configuration, and the quality of this configuration is assessed by the reward function. Specifically, if the action taken minimizes the objective function (what we aim for), a positive reward of 1/cost is assigned. However, if the action does not contribute to minimizing the objective function, the agent is penalized with a reward of -1.

This reward function has proven effective for Q-learning, where the agent explores every action in every state. However, I am encountering challenges when applying it to DQN. The unique characteristics of DQN, particularly its experience replay mechanism, seem to impact the effectiveness of the current reward strategy.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to adapt the reward function to better suit the dynamics of DQN. Your expertise and guidance in this matter would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance!